# How can debug the computer freezes

Tags: linux, windows, memory, freeze, hardware-failure

I have PC with Windows 10. My problem was in Windows. When it freezes the system immediately reboots itself. I searched about memory dump files in `%SystemRoot%` directory, but there was nothing there.

I reinstalled Windows 10 three times. I thought the problem was in some of the drivers like the USB hub. The last time I disconnected every attached adapter from the PC and installed Windows 10 and I just installed the Delphi IDE Delphi 10 and the problem shows again.

I did a memory test using Microsoft Memory Diagnostics Tool and no error shows

I did Test to my SSD using a tool from the manufacture`OCZ Trion no error on my SSD.

Today I wiped the drive totally and I installed Ubuntu 16.04, but in the past few hours the PC froze twices.

With no reboot just freezing even when I connect another keyboard the lights will not blinking.

How can I know what hardware is not working properly? How can I debug the freezing?

```
description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 vsyscall32
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          size: 31GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 3986MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits

SDD >>    /dev/sdc:
    ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       OCZ-TRION100                            
        Serial Number:      85PB57CJKMCX        
        Firmware Revision:  SAFM11.2
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.

    Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
        Product Name: Z97-D3H-CF
        Version: x.x
        Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
        Asset Tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
        Features:
            Board is a hosting board
            Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: To be filled by O.E.M.
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Comment: @Moab Updated with the hardware informations

Comment: You can stress test the memory for hours or days to see if it is time related failure of a memory module, I use this...http://memtest.org/

Comment: @Moab Thanks, i will test and come back with the results.

Comment: I think it's your memory.  Not all memory testing works to tell you exactly what's wrong.  I would buy some new memory, switch it out and see if it continues.  Memory is a tough one to diagnose since it can happen at any given time.  Did you look at the event logs?  (Just in case software did cause it).  You might want to look there.

Comment: @Moab Please make it as an answer, U suing Memtest i found one of my RAM have a lot of errors, I disconnected and try the test and every thing is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stress test the memory for hours or days to see if it is time or heat related failure of a memory module, I suggest this software [memtest.org](http://memtest.org/)